# new tab javascript links

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have a problem which has plagued me for a while. I am having a problem with links processed via javascript and right clicking -> new tab the links.  The problem is that the current functionality uses onclick="RedirectFunction();" which works great to create a dynamic link based on the parameters set on the page but does not work for right click -> new tab (or middle click)

A possible solution could be that every time filter is updated on the page, I update every link on the page to reflect the change and hard-code these new parameters into the `<a href>`. This solution, however, doesn't seem very efficient if I have lots of links on the page.

Is there a simple way to allow the users to still have right click -> new tab (or middle click) functionality whilst allowing me to continue the dynamic creation of the links when the user clicks the specific those links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `href` of the link in the `mousedown` event. This way the new `href` will be used, whether it is opening in new tab, middle click, or normal click.

```
<a id="test" href="http://www.example.com">Test Link</a>

document.querySelector('#test').addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    this.href = "http://google.com";
})
```

[Try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/qs4fx2uL/)

Comment: Strange, I'm not sure why I never thought of this.  I had added jquery event listeners for the click but not mousedown.  I have tried your example and it works perfectly.  Thanks for the extra perspective on the problem, much appreciated.